# How to implement opt out feature of Google Analytics in android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

How can we implement the opt out feature of Google Analytics in android?
Is there any method that we need to use or we need to do it using some flags(handle explicitly in the code)?
Any pointers will be of great help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up Android application for Analytics and tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863127/setting-up-android-application-for-analytics-and-tracking)

Answer (score 3):

Documentation on adding option for users to opt out from Google Analytics is available on the Developer portal now:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#opt-out

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a boolean SharedPreference that stores whether Google Analytics should be enabled or not. Before calling dispatch() on your tracker, check the preference.